# Calculate the which percentile a value belongs to in a dataframe

Tags: python, scipy

I have a dataframe with different categorical variables, year and expenditure. I would like to calculate the mean of the expenditure variable by group. Then I would like to calculate what percentile this mean corresponds to in the entire dataset of expenditures. I would like to know this percentile value for the mean of each subgroup.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
```

Create dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([])

df['year'] = np.random.randint(low=2008, high=2013, size=100000)
df['dkg'] = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100000)
df['fkg'] = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100000)
df['expenditure'] = np.random.choice([0, 25230], size=100000)
```

Calculate mean by group:

```
means = df.groupby(['fkg','dkg', 'year']).mean()
print(means)
```

Calculate corresponding percentile value for each subgroup:

```
percentile = stats.groupby(['fkg','dkg', 'year']).percentileofscore(df[['expenditure']], means)
```

This last like is giving me an error msg. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the expected output, but if I guess correctly you might want:

```
from scipy import stats

means['percentile'] = (means.groupby(['fkg','dkg', 'year'])
                            .apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(means['expenditure'], x)[0, 0])
                      )
```

output:

```
               expenditure  percentile
fkg dkg year                          
0   0   2008  12625.289560        50.0
        2009  12565.753031        40.0
        2010  12715.557991        85.0
        2011  12687.687264        75.0
        2012  12859.975976       100.0
    1   2008  12682.890173        70.0
        2009  12532.481603        35.0
        2010  12637.576059        55.0
        2011  12707.997609        80.0
        2012  12600.228337        45.0
1   0   2008  12672.511397        65.0
        2009  12510.373223        25.0
        2010  12273.914379         5.0
        2011  12423.146356        10.0
        2012  12482.421178        20.0
    1   2008  12447.964962        15.0
        2009  12518.209719        30.0
        2010  12778.573674        95.0
        2011  12736.721412        90.0
        2012  12669.934679        60.0
```

Or maybe you want a rank per 2 variables (eg. fkg/dkg):

```
means['percentile'] = means.groupby(['fkg','dkg'])['expenditure'].rank(pct=True).mul(100)
```

output:

```
               expenditure  percentile
fkg dkg year                          
0   0   2008  12625.289560        40.0
        2009  12565.753031        20.0
        2010  12715.557991        80.0
        2011  12687.687264        60.0
        2012  12859.975976       100.0
    1   2008  12682.890173        80.0
        2009  12532.481603        20.0
        2010  12637.576059        60.0
        2011  12707.997609       100.0
        2012  12600.228337        40.0
1   0   2008  12672.511397       100.0
        2009  12510.373223        80.0
        2010  12273.914379        20.0
        2011  12423.146356        40.0
        2012  12482.421178        60.0
    1   2008  12447.964962        20.0
        2009  12518.209719        40.0
        2010  12778.573674       100.0
        2011  12736.721412        80.0
        2012  12669.934679        60.0
```

Comment: Which one did you want? ;)

Comment: Actually It is not exactly what I wanted. :-) I would like to see where these values lie in the original dataframe. That is in df. So grouped by 3 variables (year, fkg, dkg) but then the percentiles based on the original column expenditure.

Comment: Then you can use the original df as reference, it's just that with the dummy data the output was weird

Comment: Like this?  means['percentile'] = (means.groupby(['fkg','dkg', 'year'])
                            .apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(df['expenditure'], x)[0, 0])
                      )    --- This doesn't work for me, gives me an error (ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().)

Comment: Can you provide a more minimal example and the matching expected output?